Using new hair curves, how do I stop interpolation going through the ears
I'm unsure if there's built-in way of doing this without diving into geometry nodes.
I can see in the interpolate nodes modifier the interpolate node takes a guide group ID which is generated from parted meshes. I'm unsure how to control this attribute to stop these hairs from interpolating between specific guides.
Is there a better way?

Interpolation guides set to 1, no intersecting.

Interpolation guides set to 4, curves intersect.
